# Display content in two-column layout in PyLaTeX?

Tags: python, pylatex

How to use `\usepackage{multicol}` in PyLaTex? What to write in python?

```latex
\begin{multicols}{2}
Column 1
\columnbreak
Column 2
\end{multicols}
```

I have found a way to display content in two-columns using PyLaTex, but I am unsure if it is the best programmatic way to do it.

What is the best PyLaTex way for displaying content in two-column?

The PyLaTeX code is as follows:

```python
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Command
from pylatex.utils import italic, NoEscape
from pylatex.package import Package
from pylatex import PageStyle, Head, MiniPage, Foot, LargeText, \
        MediumText, LineBreak, simple_page_number
from pylatex.utils import bold


lorem = '''
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
cubilia Curae; Phasellus facilisis tortor vel imperdiet vestibulum. Vivamus et
mollis risus. Proin ut enim eu leo volutpat tristique. Vivamus quam enim,
efficitur quis turpis ac, condimentum tincidunt tellus. Praesent non tellus in
quam tempor dignissim. Sed feugiat ante id mauris vehicula, quis elementum nunc
molestie. Pellentesque a vulputate nisi, ut vulputate ex. Morbi erat eros,
aliquam in justo sed, placerat tempor mauris. In vitae velit eu lorem dapibus
consequat. Integer posuere ornare laoreet.

Donec pellentesque libero id tempor aliquam. Maecenas a diam at metus varius
rutrum vel in nisl. Maecenas a est lorem. Vivamus tristique nec eros ac
hendrerit. Vivamus imperdiet justo id lobortis luctus. Sed facilisis ipsum ut
tellus pellentesque tincidunt. Mauris libero lectus, maximus at mattis ut,
venenatis eget diam. Fusce in leo at erat varius laoreet. Mauris non ipsum
pretium, convallis purus vel, pulvinar leo. Aliquam lacinia lorem dapibus
tortor imperdiet, quis consequat diam mollis.

Praesent accumsan ultrices diam a eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse accumsan
orci ut sodales ullamcorper. Integer bibendum elementum convallis. Praesent
accumsan at leo eget ullamcorper. Maecenas eget tempor enim. Quisque et nisl
eros.

'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    geometry_options = {"top":"3.5cm","bottom":"3.5cm", "left":"3.7cm",\
            "right":"4.7cm", "columnsep":"30pt"}
    doc = Document('test', geometry_options=geometry_options)

    doc.preamble.append(Command('usepackage', 'multicol'))

    doc.append(NoEscape(r'\begin{multicols}{2}'))
    doc.append(NoEscape(lorem))
    doc.append(NoEscape(r'\end{multicols}'))
    doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
    doc.generate_tex()

    tex = doc.dumps()
```

**Pdf output of my code:**
[image]

Comment: it is unrelated to python so you use it just as you would in latex,  `\usepackage{multicol}` what did you try, what error did you get?

Comment: What to write in python code for formatting multicol?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, sorry. Perhaps you should show a small complete document that does work without multicol and does not work if you add it. I have not used it but my understanding is that pytex just allows you to call python for latex so using multicol is purely a question about latex and unrelated to python. It _always_ helps to make example code in questions  a complete document that allows people to test it and see the problem.

Comment: I've edited the question and added python code what I write so far. After posting the question, I have found a way to display content in two-columns using pylatex, but I am unsure if it is the best programmatic way to do it.

Comment: @ArafatHasan I don't know `PyLaTeX` more than one gets to know after a short visit to its home page, but isn't your document missing some `import` statements?

Comment: @frougon I've not copy-pasted `import` section of my code intentionally as that is not important here to understand my code. I couldn't find any documentation on how to display two-column at https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/. And already I have made a solution to the problem, but not sure whether it's the best.

Comment: @ArafatHasan On this site, we like examples that contain a minimal amount of material but enough to demonstrate the issue, and can be compiled *as is*. This has many advantages, one of which is to remove most ambiguities.

Comment: I understand. And I have to edit the question too many times, hoping that no ambiguitions left on the question anymore.

Comment: @ArafatHasan Thank you, your code works for me (tested with Python 3.7.4). There is another way to format text in two columns in LaTeX, that is to use `\twocolumn` (`\onecolumn` to switch back) or pass `twocolumn` as a `\documentclass` option. It doesn't behave the same as `multicols`. `multicols` makes efforts to balance the columns and also doesn't force a page break when changing the column setup. You can use `multicols` inside a `minipage` or other things, it is very versatile.

Comment: In short, what you did looks fine to me (with the caveat that I don't know PyLaTeX).

Comment: That's great! I think, if you post an answer to your way, in future, will be helpful for whom facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a new environment with [`Environment`](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/own_commands_ex.html#examples.own_commands_ex.ExampleEnvironment).

```python
from pylatex import UnsafeCommand
from pylatex.base_classes import Environment
from pylatex.utils import NoEscape

class MultiColumnEnvironment(Environment):

    _latex_name = 'MultiColumn'
    packages = [Package('multicol')]

def main():
    geometry_options = {"top":"3.5cm","bottom":"3.5cm", "left":"3.7cm",\
        "right":"4.7cm", "columnsep":"30pt"}
    doc = Document('test', geometry_options=geometry_options)

    ...

    new_env = UnsafeCommand('newenvironment', 'MultiColumn',
                            extra_arguments=[r'\begin{multicols}{2}', r'\end{multicols}'])
    doc.append(new_env)

    with doc.create(MultiColumnEnvironment()) as environment:
        environment.append(NoEscape(lorem))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```